# numpy array using np.arange converted to pd data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following

```
x= np.arange(80,95,1)
y= np.arange(175,185,1)
```

I want to create pandas data frame containing x and y?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) to create a dataframe from different length arrays, and transpose the result if you want the arrays as columns:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records([x,y]).T

     0      1
0   80.0  175.0
1   81.0  176.0
2   82.0  177.0
3   83.0  178.0
4   84.0  179.0
5   85.0  180.0
6   86.0  181.0
7   87.0  182.0
8   88.0  183.0
9   89.0  184.0
10  90.0    NaN
11  91.0    NaN
12  92.0    NaN
13  93.0    NaN
14  94.0    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((x, y)), columns=["x", "y"])
```

There are probably other ways to do this, the DataFrame object can be constructed in a lot of different ways.

Edit: this actually won't work with different shapes of columns, but can be used with columns of the same length

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
```

Comment: Can you explain yourself better please? I think my answer does provide an answer to OP's question. He has already defined `x` and `y` and with my code he can turn them into a `DataFrame`.